# Finding which byte position differs between files with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I've been looking for a Python 3 script that finds what bytes (or rather, their position) differ between two files of identical size. Filecmp only gives True/False and none of the other scripts I've found have been working. I made this, and while it works for smaller files, it's super slow for big files. Does anyone have a better (read: faster) script? Or a way to improve mine to make it faster.

```
#Get file length
items = [a,b,c]
file = open(a,"rb")
filelength = len(file.read())
file.close()

#Create dictionaries where bytes will be stored
comp = {}
compare = {}
for i in range(0,filelength):
    comp[i] = []
    compare[i] = {}

#Add bytes to dictionaries
for i in items:
    file = open(i,"rb")
    k = file.read(1)
    count = 0
    while k:
        comp[count].append(k)
        k = file.read(1)
        count = count + 1
    file.close()

#Get if the byte at the same position is identical to the others or not
for i in range(0,filelength):
    for n in comp[i]:
        if n in compare[i]:
            compare[i][n] = compare[i][n] + 1
        else:
            compare[i][n] = 1

#Print which byte differs
for i in compare:
    if compare[i][max(compare[i], key=compare[i].get)] < len(items):
        print("Byte number: " + str(i+1))
```

Comment: Am I interpreting your code correctly, that items contains a list of files to be compared to one another and you desire to know where in each file any mismatches occur?

Comment: @itprorh66 Yes, exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is any faster than your solution, but it is simpler to implement.

The functions being used:

```
def read_byte(afl):
    rslt = [None]*len(afl)
    for i in range(len(afl)):
        if afl[i]:
            rslt[i] = afl[i].read(1)
    return rslt   
                
def closeFiles(afl):
    for f in afl:
        f.close
        
def all_bytes_equal(data):
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        if data[0] != data[i]:
            return False
    return True

def compareFiles(flist):
    active_files = [None] * len(flist)
    byte_count = 0
    for i in range(len(flist)):
        active_files[i] = open(flist[i],"rb")
    while True:
        data = read_byte(active_files)
        if all_bytes_equal(data):
            if data[0] == b'':
                print ("All files compare")
                closeFiles(active_files)
                break
            byte_count += 1
        else:
            for i in range(1, len(active_files)):
                if data[0] != data[i]:
                    print(f"File {file_list[i]} differs at byte count {byte_count}")
            closeFiles(active_files)
            break
```

The implementation:

```
file_list = ['test1.txt','test2.txt','test3.txt'] #list of paths to each file being compared
compareFiles(file_list)
```